# Всплывающее подменю

Tags: jquery, события, hover

http://jsfiddle.net/eje7msuo/3/
При mouseenter на красный блок появится зеленый блок. Надо, чтоб зеленый блок исчез не только при mouseleave с зеленого блока, но и с красного. Но при этом чтоб, покидая красный блок, переходя на зеленый в первый раз, меню не закрывалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.showSubMenu').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.SubMenu').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.SubMenu').hide();
});
$('.SubMenu').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.SubMenu').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.SubMenu').hide();
});
```

upd: забыл же про переход, поправил.

Comment: @daerokin, да-да, я подправил, я просто забыл.

Comment: Спасибо. Это мне помогло.